# Undefined procedure: (=)/4

Tags: prolog, dcg

I want to compare two terms in SWI-Prolog:

```
np(np(DetBaum,NBaum),Morph1)->det(DetBaum,Morph1),n(NBaum,Morph2),Morph1=Morph2.
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (=)/4  
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:  
ERROR:         (=)/2
```

I thought Morph1 and Morph2 are two terms, not four. Am I wrong?

Comment: You wrote `->`. I assume your code actually has `-->`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In grammar rules, calls to predicate such as `=/2` must be wrapped using the `{}/1` control construct:

```
np(np(DetBaum, NBaum), Morph1) -->
    det(DetBaum, Morph1),
    n(NBaum, Morph2),
    {Morph1 = Morph2}.
```

This prevents the compilation of the grammar rule to interpret `=/2` as a non-terminal.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Paulo said, I would like to mention that using `(=)/2` here is not necessary. After all, if the terms are equal, then you can simply use the same variable to denote them both.

So, your whole rule can be written as:

```
np(np(DetBaum,NBaum), Morph) -->
        det(DetBaum, Morph),
        n(NBaum, Morph).
```